# How to include javascript dynamically in this real world example?

Tags: javascript

I read here it is possible to inlcude js dynamically
http://www.phpied.com/javascript-include/

I wanted to try with this real example by concerting tigra slider example (see http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_slider_control/multiple_slider_designs_demo.html) into dynamic code using http://accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/ to convert static code to dynamic one:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="float: left;position:relative">
<div id="slider1" style="float: left">
<script language="JavaScript">
    var A_TPL = {
        'b_vertical': false,
        'b_watch': true,
        'n_controlWidth': 120,
        'n_controlHeight': 16,
        'n_sliderWidth': 16,
        'n_sliderHeight': 15,
        'n_pathLeft': 1,
        'n_pathTop': 1,
        'n_pathLength': 103,
        's_imgControl': 'img/blueh_bg.gif',
        's_imgSlider': 'img/blueh_sl.gif',
        'n_zIndex': 1
    }

    var A_INIT1 = {
        's_form': 0,
        's_name': 'sliderValue1',
        'n_minValue': 0,
        'n_maxValue': 100,
        'n_value': 20,
        'n_step': 1
    }
    new slider(A_INIT1, A_TPL);
</script>
</div>

<div style="float: left">
<input name="sliderValue" id="sliderValue1" type="Text" size="3" >
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<div style="float: left;position:relative">
<div style="float: left">
<script language="JavaScript">
    var A_INIT2 = {
        's_form': 0,
        's_name': 'sliderValue2',
        'n_minValue': -50,
        'n_maxValue': 50,
        'n_value': 0,
        'n_step': 1
    }
    new slider(A_INIT2, A_TPL);
</script>
</div>
<div style="float: left">
<input name="sliderValue" id="sliderValue2" type="Text" size="3">
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<div style="float: left;position:relative">
<div style="float: left">
<script language="JavaScript">
    var A_INIT3 = {
        's_form': 0,
        's_name': 'sliderValue3',
        'n_minValue': -100,
        'n_maxValue': 0,
        'n_value': -20,
        'n_step': 1
    }

    new slider(A_INIT3, A_TPL);
</script>
</div>
<div style="float: left">
<input name="sliderValue" id="sliderValue3" type="Text" size="3">
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

which will give

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="slider.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.html" method="get" name="demoForm">
<script>
document.write("<table>");
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>");
document.write("<div style=\"float: left;position:relative\">");
document.write("<div id=\"slider1\" style=\"float: left\">");
document.write("<script language=\"JavaScript\">");
document.write("    var A_TPL = {");
document.write("        'b_vertical': false,");
document.write("        'b_watch': true,");
document.write("        'n_controlWidth': 120,");
document.write("        'n_controlHeight': 16,");
document.write("        'n_sliderWidth': 16,");
document.write("        'n_sliderHeight': 15,");
document.write("        'n_pathLeft': 1,");
document.write("        'n_pathTop': 1,");
document.write("        'n_pathLength': 103,");
document.write("        's_imgControl': 'img\/blueh_bg.gif',");
document.write("        's_imgSlider': 'img\/blueh_sl.gif',");
document.write("        'n_zIndex': 1");
document.write("    }");
document.write("");
document.write("    var A_INIT1 = {");
document.write("        's_form': 0,");
document.write("        's_name': 'sliderValue1',");
document.write("        'n_minValue': 0,");
document.write("        'n_maxValue': 100,");
document.write("        'n_value': 20,");
document.write("        'n_step': 1");
document.write("    }");
document.write("    new slider(A_INIT1, A_TPL);");
document.write("<\/script>");
document.write("<\/div>");
document.write("");
document.write("<div style=\"float: left\">");
document.write("<input name=\"sliderValue\" id=\"sliderValue1\" type=\"Text\" size=\"3\" >");
document.write("<\/div>");
document.write("<\/div>");
document.write("<\/td>");
document.write("<\/tr>");
document.write("");
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>");
document.write("<div style=\"float: left;position:relative\">");
document.write("<div style=\"float: left\">");
document.write("<script language=\"JavaScript\">");
document.write("    var A_INIT2 = {");
document.write("        's_form': 0,");
document.write("        's_name': 'sliderValue2',");
document.write("        'n_minValue': -50,");
document.write("        'n_maxValue': 50,");
document.write("        'n_value': 0,");
document.write("        'n_step': 1");
document.write("    }");
document.write("    new slider(A_INIT2, A_TPL);");
document.write("<\/script>");
document.write("<\/div>");
document.write("<div style=\"float: left\">");
document.write("<input name=\"sliderValue\" id=\"sliderValue2\" type=\"Text\" size=\"3\">");
document.write("<\/div>");
document.write("<\/div>");
document.write("<\/td>");
document.write("<\/tr>");
document.write("");
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>");
document.write("<div style=\"float: left;position:relative\">");
document.write("<div style=\"float: left\">");
document.write("<script language=\"JavaScript\">");
document.write("    var A_INIT3 = {");
document.write("        's_form': 0,");
document.write("        's_name': 'sliderValue3',");
document.write("        'n_minValue': -100,");
document.write("        'n_maxValue': 0,");
document.write("        'n_value': -20,");
document.write("        'n_step': 1");
document.write("    }");
document.write("");
document.write("    new slider(A_INIT3, A_TPL);");
document.write("<\/script>");
document.write("<\/div>");
document.write("<div style=\"float: left\">");
document.write("<input name=\"sliderValue\" id=\"sliderValue3\" type=\"Text\" size=\"3\">");
document.write("<\/div>");
document.write("<\/div>");
document.write("<\/td>");
document.write("<\/tr>");
document.write("<\/table>");
document.write("");
</script>

<input name="Submit" type="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But only fields appear no slider when running the document. Why ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Please make your example shorter - maybe you use document.write only for demonstration purposes, avoid it in production code at all costs.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add a script to the page dynamically, do it by injecting a `<script src="..."></script>` tag into the `<head>`. Injecting script content directly onto the page is, as you've seen, problematic.

Comment: This is the basic classical static way that everybody knows of course this is not dynamic. Dynamic means you can include a script at runtime that would be stored in a variable.

Comment: *"This is the basic classical static way that everybody knows..."* Everybody does **not** know it. You said you wanted to dynamically load scripts, which this does. You didn't say the script *content* had to be dynamic. If you find yourself in a situation where the script *content* has to be dynamic as well, odds are good a bit of refactoring is required.

Comment: @voteyDisciiple is saying the same thing as your link - add <script> tag to head (but please you "the dom way" as described in the article you link)

Comment: Naturally the script you include can be generated dynamically.

Comment: @Crowler please don't consider me more stupid than I seem to be to you :) It's up to me to judge whereas I do need it or not. My question is not about your judgment on this, it's about if you know HOW to do this or not and if yes of course give details with code snippet. I know javascript programming since the internet exists so I'm not absolute beginner on this language

Comment: So what I'm looking for is guru's knowledge.

Comment: Understood. You've gotten advice from a couple gurus here. Please let us know if we can help with any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use document.write. Use .innerHTML instead to add HTML to document.

Also you cannot add javascript to document like that. You need to eval() it (and that's very bad practice) or, much better, write a function which can be executed when you need it.

Comment: I would have bolded it like this: **Do not use `document.write`**

Comment: *"Don't use `document.write`"* = good. *"Use .innerHTML instead"* = enh, not a great idea for script content. *"Also you cannot add javascript to a document like that. You need to eval() it"* = bad. You don't need eval(). Use a `script` tag.

Comment: 1°) innerHTML may cause problem with old browsers which I need to be compatible with in big corp environments some have still not upgrade/

Answer (score 0):

i'd presume that you need to do something in the document or body onload events.

my 'normal' javascript is a bit rusty, so i won't attempt an example, tho there are plenty around to get a feel from.

that's my gut feel anyway..